# PHP include condition in if only when criteria matched

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to build an `if then` statement with criteria including/excluding the final criterias.

Example :

```
$vanilla_on=true;
$sugar_on=false;
$flour_on=true;

$vanilla=10;
$sugar=2;
$flour=100;

// As I set $vanilla_on to false, it doesn't appear in my if statement, if it was set to true, it would be added && ($vanilla < 100)
if ( ($sugar>2) && ($flour>90) )
{
  // ok
}
```

Basically, I only want to check the vanilla, sugar, and flour conditions if the corresponding boolean values are set to true. So if I have vanilla_on=false, it won't matter how many units of vanilla are included as we'll only be checking the sugar and flour conditions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't see `$vanilla_on` in your if statement.

Comment: What are you trying to do `actually` ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is it you are actually asking?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I have a list of criterias I want to test in an if statement, vanilla, sugar, flour. I want to test each of them only if they are marked to be tested. If they aren't, they won't appear in the if statement.

Comment: I get what you're asking. It wasn't clear at first, but it is an interesting question. +1  Hope you learn from my edit how to make your posts clearer in the future. Good luck! :)

Comment: What I find odd with your approach is that why, if one property doesn't need to be checked, has it a quantity anyhow? Why isn't `$vanilla` `null` in that case?

Comment: jmort253 thanks for the edit too. I was a bit sick and couldn't find a way to explain clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// these are "switches" that will tell the if statement which components to check
$vanilla_on=true;
$sugar_on=false;
$flour_on=true;

// components
$vanilla=10;
$sugar=2;
$flour=100;

// only check that the component meets the thresholds *if* it's "on"
if ( ($sugar>2 || !$sugar_on) && ($flour>90 || !$flour_on) && ($vanilla < 100 || !$vanilla_on) )
{
  // ok
  echo "OKAY!";
}
```

The way this works is this:  You have an if statement that must evaluate to TRUE for things to be "okay". Assuming you need all three components to be checked to make sure they all are within the thresholds, all 3 conditions must be true in order for the entire statement to evaluate to true.  If just one condition in the AND is false, the entire thing is false.

But let's say you don't care about how much vanilla is used. As long as sugar and flour are measured within the threshold, how much vanilla you use is irrelevant in determining if things are okay. To do this, you wrap each individual component in parenthesis and OR it with its corresponding "on" boolean.

In short, if $vanilla_on is false, meaning you don't care how much vanilla you use, you take the opposite value of the boolean, true, and OR it with your threshold comparison. Since (true OR false) always evaluates to true, that part of the if statement always returns true no matter how much vanilla you use.  Likewise, if $sugar_on is true, the opposite value is false, so in order for that part of the if statement to be true, we now rely solely on the sugar threshold to fall within the bounds determined via the less than comparison.

In short, break the problem down into individual components, then AND them all together.

Answer (score 1):

```
$vanilla_ok = true;
if ($vanilla_on === true && $vanilla < 5) {
    $vanilla_ok = false;
}

if (... && $vanilla_ok)
{
    // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a simple way to do it.

```
if (a)
{
if (b) {c=true} else {c=false}
}
else
{
c=true
}

repeat for all _on variables

if (c) && (d) ...
```